# Can a wire go bad

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

I recently touched a wire on fuse box and now I have no power. Fuses are all good breaker good. Can the wire be dead? Is that a thing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Could you post a picture of your electric panel and the wire you "touched"?

Comment: When you say you touched the wire did you short it? Arc and sparks?  In that case I would be rechecking the fuse as it probably opened.

Answer (score 1):

Wires don't go bad, but wire connections can become loose. They can also develop a burnish or tarnish on the surface which can result in a poor electrical connection, lading to an increase in electeical resistance, which in turn can create a hot spot and melt nearby wire insulation, maybe even start a fire.

Comment: Wires do go bad! Insulation fails over time. The conductors get corrosion and break. These are typically unique situations though where the wire is old and/or moisture is getting into the wire.  Is this a house? Location? What stopped working? What is on the circuit?